# Find available quantity from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a logic to find available quantity in location,
for the location and quantity is managed with dictionary,

```
d={'loc2': 500.0, 'loc3': 200.0, 'loc1': 1000.0, 'loc4': 100.0, 'loc5': 50.0}

def find_combination(locations,qty): 
    new_list = sorted(locations.items(),key=lambda y: y[1],reverse=True)
    result = []
    while qty > 0:
        min_item = ''
        for item in new_list:
            if item[0] in result: 
                continue
            new_diff = abs(qty - item[1])
            if not min_item or new_diff <= min_diff:
                min_item = item[0]
                min_diff = new_diff
                min_val = item[1]
        result.append((min_item ,locations.get(min_item)))
        qty = qty - min_val
    return result
```

Now when the quantity is nelow the max qty in the dict it's giving unexpected result,

```
print find_combination(d,500)
OUTPUT: [('loc2', 500.0)]
print find_combination(d,1000)
OUTPUT: [('loc1', 1000.0)]
print find_combination(d,750)
OUTPUT: [('loc2', 500.0), ('loc3', 200.0), ('loc5', 50.0)]
print find_combination(d,1800)
OUTPUT: [('loc1', 1000.0), ('loc1', 1000.0)] # unexpected
```

Comment: I believe you need to initialize min_diff variable. But that might not be the solution.

Comment: Will you please mention what is the expected output? What logic you want to implement.

Comment: the abs makes 1000 closer to 800 than 500.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, the problem was that "            if item[0] in result: 
                continue" did not filter 'loc1' after it already used it once?

Comment: @Lafada it'll be like [('loc1', 1000.0), ('loc2', 500.0), ('loc3', 200.0), ('loc4': 100.0)].

Comment: @Heliconia do you allow repeating the keys to obtain the combination or they must be unique?

Answer (score 2):

Could you explain why that output is unexpected?  After one `loc1` item has been appended to `result`, the value of `qty` will be `800`.  The line `new_diff = abs(qty - item[1])` will return a minimal value (200) for the item `loc1` again on the next iteration, so that item will be added to `result` once again.  Once that's been done, `qty` will be `-200`, so the `while` loop will terminate.  Should you only be adding items if their associated quantity is smaller than the variable `qty`?  If so, you need more logic to do that - you could change the for loop to:

```
for item in [x for x in new_list if x[1] <= qty]:
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you would want:

```
d={'loc2': 500.0, 'loc3': 200.0, 'loc1': 1000.0, 'loc4': 100.0, 'loc5': 50.0}
from operator import itemgetter
def find_combination(locs,qty):
    locs = sorted(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True) #get them in descending order
    result = []
    for loc,val in locs:
        if qty <= 0: #if we've reached the target qty then need to look no further
            break
        elif qty - val >= 0: #if we can take the val of a location and not go below zero do so
            qty -= val
            result.append((loc,val)) 
    return result
```

Which when you

```
print find_combination(d,1800)
[('loc1', 1000.0), ('loc2', 500.0), ('loc3', 200.0), ('loc4', 100.0)]
>>>
```

Comment: it will break in case loc have law qty,
try,
find_combination(d,34)
it will not give blank list in case of it should give [('loc5', 50.0)]

Comment: @AtulMakwana you are right! it's breaking.

Comment: @AtulMakwana my interpretation was that there would be an exact match from the data.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following code do what you want? I have used the integer division to keep track of the remaining quantity.

```
def find_combination(locations,qty): 
    new_list = sorted(locations.items(),key=lambda y: y[1],reverse=True)
    result = []
    for item in new_list:
        quotient = int(qty / item[1])
        result.extend(quotient*[item])
        qty -= quotient*item[1]
    return result
```

EDIT: Since you have used a check `if item[0] not in result`, I am assuming that you don't want to repeat any item in the result. In that case, HennyH's answer will work fine. This answer will not work. But if repetition is allowed, then this one would work.