# Find the relative quantity from the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a logic to find available quantity in location,
for the location and quantity is managed with dictionary:

```
d={'loc2': 500.0, 'loc3': 200.0, 'loc1': 1000.0, 'loc4': 100.0, 'loc5': 50.0}

from operator import itemgetter
def find_combination(locs,qty):
    locs = sorted(locs.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    result = []
    for loc,val in locs:
        if qty <= 0:
            break
        elif qty - val >= 0:
            qty -= val
            result.append((loc,val))
    return result
```

Now when the quantity is below the max qty in the dict it's giving these unexpected result:

```
print find_combination(d,1000)
[('loc1', 1000.0)]
print find_combination(d,750)
[('loc2', 500.0), ('loc3', 200.0), ('loc5', 50.0)]
print find_combination(d,1900)
[('loc1', 1000.0), ('loc2', 500.0), ('loc3', 200.0), ('loc4', 100.0), ('loc5', 50.0)] 
print find_combination(d,150)
[('loc4', 100.0), ('loc5', 50.0)]
print find_combination(d,34)
[] # unexpected  # should be [('loc5', 50.0)]
print find_combination(d,88)
[('loc5', 50.0)] # should be [('loc4', 100.0)]
```

Comment: You've neglected the case `qty - val < 0`.

Comment: didn't you ask this before [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17164496/832621)?

Comment: @sgpc yes but not satisfied with the answer. see the approved answer.

Comment: you could just disaprove the answer and wait for another one that satisfies you ....

Comment: @sgpc I am going to do that, but to redefine my question I re-asked it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure if you algorithm is the one you need. If the idea is to get a certain quantity from different location then your algorithm will not find the optimal combination, just a good one.

Your problem can be viewed as a [0-1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which can be solved in a pseudo polynomial time using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary storing all possible combinations using the dictionray keys only once, which will give:

```
d={'loc2': 500.0, 'loc3': 200.0, 'loc1': 1000.0, 'loc4': 100.0, 'loc5': 50.0}
from itertools import combinations
comb = {}
for i in range(1,len(d)):
    [comb.__setitem__(sum(j),k) for k,j in zip(combinations(d.keys()  ,i),
                                               combinations(d.values(),i))]
```

The `comb` dictionary looks like:

```
{50.0: ('loc5',),
 100.0: ('loc4',),
 150.0: ('loc4', 'loc5'),
 200.0: ('loc3',),
 250.0: ('loc3', 'loc5'),
 300.0: ('loc3', 'loc4'),
 350.0: ('loc3', 'loc4', 'loc5'),
 500.0: ('loc2',),
 550.0: ('loc2', 'loc5'),
 600.0: ('loc2', 'loc4'),
 650.0: ('loc2', 'loc4', 'loc5'),
 700.0: ('loc2', 'loc3'),
 750.0: ('loc2', 'loc3', 'loc5'),
 800.0: ('loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4'),
 850.0: ('loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4', 'loc5'),
 1000.0: ('loc1',),
 1050.0: ('loc1', 'loc5'),
 1100.0: ('loc1', 'loc4'),
 1150.0: ('loc1', 'loc4', 'loc5'),
 1200.0: ('loc3', 'loc1'),
 1250.0: ('loc3', 'loc1', 'loc5'),
 1300.0: ('loc3', 'loc1', 'loc4'),
 1350.0: ('loc3', 'loc1', 'loc4', 'loc5'),
 1500.0: ('loc2', 'loc1'),
 1550.0: ('loc2', 'loc1', 'loc5'),
 1600.0: ('loc2', 'loc1', 'loc4'),
 1650.0: ('loc2', 'loc1', 'loc4', 'loc5'),
 1700.0: ('loc2', 'loc3', 'loc1'),
 1750.0: ('loc2', 'loc3', 'loc1', 'loc5'),
 1800.0: ('loc2', 'loc3', 'loc1', 'loc4')}
```

Then, you can build a function to chekc if a given combination exists:

```
 find_combination = lambda num: comb.get(num, 'NOT A VALID COMBINATION')
```

Examples:

```
 find_combination(1750)
 #('loc2', 'loc3', 'loc1', 'loc5')

 find_combination(1):
 #'NOT A VALID COMBINATION'
```

---

EDIT: if your dictionary gets too big it is better to use this function based on iterators:

```
def find_combination(d, num):
    from itertools import combinations,izip
    t = ((sum(j),k) for i in range(1,len(d)) \
                    for j,k in izip(combinations(d.values(),i),
                                    combinations(d.keys()  ,i)))
    for comb,k in t:
        if comb==num: return k
```

Comment: This might work for a small list, but will take foreve of r a list containing 100+ items.

Answer (score 0):

How is this an unexpected result?

When `qty = 34` and `val = 50`, `qty - val >= 0` will evaluate to false.

Similar to the case where `qty = 88` and `val = 100`

The result of your program sounds good to me :)

On a side note:

```
def find_combination(locs,qty):
  locs = sorted(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

but I guess you mean `locs = sorted(locs.items(), ...`

Comment: The program is always right :) The algorithm, however, might be wrong ;)

Comment: also agree with @icseth. It's just unrelated to my answer. The OP mentioned unexpected results and I explained those.